# change Full Calendar event height ONLY in dayView

Tags: fullcalendar

Full Calendar dayView height adjustments seem impossible.  I have looked and tried just about everything. I can get the height adjustments but the events overlap? I have seen several posts on stackoverflow but none that fix my issue.

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
                console.log($(view));
                //$('div.fc-day-content').css({"height":"50px"});
                $('.fc-event').css({"height":"50px"});

             },
```

here is the CSS it spits out.

```
element.style {
    background-color: #2E3436;
    border-color: #2E3436;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 50px;
    left: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
    width: 1439px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the view you want to set the height for is basicDay, what you need is something like

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if(view.name === 'basicDay') {
        $(element).height(100);
    }
}
```

See [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MsjjW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because the elements have "position: absolute" and each one is set beneath the other by the 'top' attribute, so if you change all of their heights they'll overflow and block each other, what i did was to change their height but also Increase their distance from the the top, using:

```
$('.fc-event').css('height', '100px');
```

and then -

```
$('.fc-event').css('top', function(i, v) {
return (((parseFloat(v)-18)/20)*100 + 18) + 'px';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

yes , you can do it in event render option

```
 eventRender: function (event, element,view) {
                 debugger; 
             if(view.type == "agendaDay"){
                 $('.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td').css('height','2.8em');}
             else
                 $('.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td').css('height','1.8em');}
```